# Is it risky to use an underpowered laptop power adapter?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I own an Acer VX15, which comes with a 135W power adapter.

When I forgot it, I bought a 90W ISY universal adapter from a local hardware store. The idea was, that it shouldn't cause anything but a slowly loading battery and that, at worst, short term full-capacity loads of the laptop while gaming should be covered by draining the battery. During day to day web-browsing use it draws well below 50W after all, and can draw as little as 10-15W when using an external monitor.

But does this assumption actually hold? Or will a powerful laptop cause an underspecified power adapter to overheat?

A similar question ([How risky is it to use an underspecified charger?](https://superuser.com/questions/443102/how-risky-is-it-to-use-an-underspecified-charger)) has been asked for mobile power supplies only. Due to the order of magnitude lower power involved, the answer likely can't be transferred though.

Comment: It can shorten the life of your lithium ion battery by improper charge cycles. The computer may also run alot slower. It's best to get the OEM charger honestly.

Comment: You can minimize risk by not charging while trying to use the laptop.  The OEM adapter has the power to do both.  Charge the battery with the laptop off.  With a full battery, it won't try to charge it if you operate on the adapter.  The biggest risk is probably to the adapter; you may destroy it if you try to draw more power from it than it was designed to provide.

Comment: When you draw too many **amps** the voltage goes down, and the wires will start to get warm or hot.  In the extreme to catch fire, if the problem isn't resolved before then.  However, if you keep it under the threshold it is not a problem, the only issue is how do you keep ensure you don't go over the threshold.